# Javascript: Dynamically add functions to object

Tags: javascript, function, dynamic

I have a `GeneralWrapper` object that calls the statically-defined functions in the `Library1` and `Library2` objects.

The aim is that by calling `GeneralWrapper.someFunc()`, this will also call `Library1.someFunc()` and `Library2.someFunc()` without me having to explicitly create a function in `GeneralWrapper` called `someFunc`.

I attempt to implement this in the `__preamble` method below:

```
var GeneralWrapper = {

    __modespopulated: false,

    __validmodes: {     // All 3 of these
        spoonFunc: 1,   //  functions exist
        knifeFunc: 1,   //  in Library1 and
         forkFunc: 1    //  Library2
    },

    __switchMode: function(funcname){

        if (funcname in GeneralWrapper.__validmodes){
            console.log("calling function", funcname)

            GeneralWrapper.__preamble()

            Library1[ funcname ](); // Call mode in Library1
            Library2[ funcname ](); // Call mode in Library2
        }
    },

    /* Attach valid modes to General Wrapper at runtime */
    __preamble: function(){
        if (!GeneralWrapper.__modespopulated)
        {
            for (var mode in GeneralWrapper.__validmodes)
            {
                GeneralWrapper[mode] = function(){
                    GeneralWrapper.__switchMode(mode)
                };
            }

            GeneralWrapper.__modespopulated = true
        }

        GeneralWrapper.__otherprestuff();
    },


    __otherprestuff: function(){
        // Stuff
    },

    funcThatAlwaysGetsCalled: function(){
        GeneralWrapper.__switchMode("forkFunc");
    }    
}

var Library1 = { 
     forkFunc(){console.log("Lib1","fork")},
    spoonFunc(){console.log("Lib1","spoon")},
    knifeFunc(){console.log("Lib1","knife")}
}

var Library2 = { 
     forkFunc(){console.log("Lib2","FORK")},
    spoonFunc(){console.log("Lib2","SPOON")},
    knifeFunc(){console.log("Lib2","KNIFE")}
}

// Okay, let's initialise the object
GeneralWrapper.funcThatAlwaysGetsCalled();
```

For some reason calls to `GeneralWrapper.spoonFunc()` and `GeneralWrapper.knifeFunc()` always defer to the Fork output.

I imagine the problem stems from the anonymous function assignment on the `GeneralWrapper[mode] = blah` line where JS treats it as the same function each time, but I don't know how to get around this.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution:

Change this line:

```
for (var mode in GeneralWrapper.__validmodes)
```

into this:

```
for (let mode in GeneralWrapper.__validmodes)
```

---

#### Explanation:

what happens in your code (when binding functions in `__preamble`'s loop) is that you create an anonymous function, which is totally fine. The problem is, your anon function has received the `mode` as a reference to local variable, so it's value is not automatically cloned but rather accessed at runtime. The main problem is that you've used `var` keyword, which means "hoisted variable" (it gets declared at the top of the function it was defined inside, even if it's somewhere in the middle of your function's code). In this scenario, you need a "block-scoped" variable, which will be bound to each loop iteration separately.

You can read more about variables hostings on MDN:
[`var` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)
[`let` at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)

One thing you have to know - `let` was introduced in ES2015, so if you worry about backward compatibility with older browsers, you either have to use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) or [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)

Comment: wow I never knew! I'm using `strict mode` so I just assumed that `var` scope was always locked tight. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

One potential problem here is that you're creating functions inside a loop which can lead to some performance problems or unexpected behavior.

I'd replace:

```
for (var mode in GeneralWrapper.__validmodes)
{
    GeneralWrapper[mode] = function(){
        GeneralWrapper.__switchMode(mode)
    };
}
```

with:

```
for (var mode in GeneralWrapper.__validmodes)
{
    GeneralWrapper[mode] = GeneralWrapper.__switchMode.bind(this, mode);
}
```

Which should solve the problem at hand.

Comment: thank you, I went with the other answer for the reading material